# Malliavin derivative with respect to part of samples.

Tags: probability, stochastic-integrals, stochastic-analysis, stochastic-pde, malliavin-calculus

My question came from [M. Hairer's paper "Homogenization of periodic linear degenerate PDEs" (page 2469)](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0022123608001699), I think it could be regarded as a basic exercise of Malliavin calculus thought. I will put is into a nutshell.

> Let $\Omega$ and $\bar\Omega$ be two independent copies of $1$-dimensional Wiener space, and denote by $B$ and $\bar B$ the corresponding canonical Wiener processes, $\tau$ is a stopping time defined on $\Omega$. Now define a process $W$ on the product space $\Omega\times\bar\Omega$ by
>   \begin{equation}
> W_t(\omega,\bar\omega)=\left\{
> \begin{split}
> B_t(\omega) & \quad\text{for } t\le\tau(\omega), \\
> B_\tau(\omega)+\bar B_{t-\tau}(\bar\omega) & \quad\text{for } t\ge\tau(\omega).
> \end{split}
> \right.
> \end{equation}
>   Then it is easy to see that $W$ is again a $1$-dimensional Wiener process. Consider the process $X_t$ which is the solution of the SDE
>   $$\tag{SDE}
> X_t=x+\int_0^tb(X_r)\,dr+\int_0^t\sigma(X_r)\,dW_r.
> $$
>   We suppose the coefficients $b$ and $\sigma$ to be smooth enough such that (SDE) has an unique solution and $X_t\in\mathbb D^\infty$.
>
> **My question is**: How to calculate the Malliavin derivative $\mathcal D_sX_t$ **with respect to $\bar B$**?

I know I could refer to [Theorem 2.2.1 of Nualart's book "Malliavin Calculus And Related Topics"](https://books.google.co.jp/books?id=PhXrBwAAQBAJ&pg=PA102&dq=The+Malliavin+Calculus+and+Related+Topics+Weak+differentiability+of+the+solution&hl=zh-CN&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwi-0NWQhqbQAhVLTLwKHSZ6DGUQ6AEIHTAA#v=onepage&q=The%20Malliavin%20Calculus%20and%20Related%20Topics%20Weak%20differentiability%20of%20the%20solution&f=false), but how to treat the case of Malliavin derivative  w.r.t part of samples?

Any comments will be appreciate. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, finally I find it out by myself.

From (SDE), 
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
X_t(\omega,\bar\omega)= &\ x+\int_0^tb(X_r)\,dr+\mathbf 1_{[0,\tau(\omega))}(t)\int_0^t\sigma(X_r)\,dB_r(\omega) \\
& +\mathbf 1_{[\tau(\omega),+\infty)}(t)\bigg(\int_0^{\tau(\omega)}\sigma(X_r)\,dB_r(\omega)+\int_{\tau(\omega)}^t\sigma(X_r)\,d\bar B_{r-\tau(\omega)}(\bar\omega)\bigg).
\end{split}
\end{equation}
Thus,
\begin{align}
\mathcal D_s^{\bar\omega}X_t &=
\begin{aligned}[t] \mathbf 1_{[s,+\infty)}(t)\bigg\{ & \int_s^tDb(X_r)\mathcal D_s^{\bar\omega}X_r\,dr+\mathbf 1_{[0,\tau(\omega))}(t)\int_s^tD\sigma(X_r)\mathcal D_s^{\bar\omega}X_r\,dB_r(\omega) \\
& \begin{aligned}
+\mathbf 1_{[\tau(\omega),+\infty)}(t) \bigg[ & 
\sigma(X_s)+\mathbf 1_{[\tau(\omega),+\infty)}(s)\int_s^tD\sigma(X_r)\mathcal D_s^{\bar\omega}X_r\,d\bar B_{r-\tau(\omega)}(\bar\omega) \\
& \begin{aligned}
+\mathbf 1_{[0,\tau(\omega))}(s)\bigg( & \int_s^{\tau(\omega)}D\sigma(X_r)\mathcal D_s^{\bar\omega}X_r\,dB_r(\omega) \\
& \begin{aligned}
+\int_{\tau(\omega)}^tD\sigma(X_r)\mathcal D_s^{\bar\omega}X_r\,d\bar B_{r-\tau(\omega)}(\bar\omega)\bigg) \bigg]\bigg\}
\end{aligned}
\end{aligned}
\end{aligned}
\end{aligned}\\
&= 
\begin{aligned}[t] \mathbf 1_{[s,+\infty)}(t)\bigg\{ & \int_s^tDb(X_r)\mathcal D_s^{\bar\omega}X_r\,dr+\mathbf 1_{[0,\tau(\omega))}(t)\int_s^tD\sigma(X_r)\mathcal D_s^{\bar\omega}X_r\,dW_r \\
& \begin{aligned}
+\mathbf 1_{[\tau(\omega),+\infty)}(t) \bigg[ & 
\sigma(X_s)+\int_s^tD\sigma(X_r)\mathcal D_s^{\bar\omega}X_r\,dW_r \bigg]\bigg\}.
\end{aligned}
\end{aligned}
\end{align}